# Asp.Net Core 3.1 HttpConfigurationKey

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

We need to migrate a .net WebApi application to .net core 3.1 web api.

In the API extension method the following is showing an error.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Properties.Add(System.Web.Http.Hosting.HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration());
```

as the old package used is not compatible. what is the alternative package or solution for this?

Comment: Have you installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package (`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`)?

Answer (score 0):

Installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` package(`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`).In my code,it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I tried to install the package it's showing a warning .  "This package may not be fully compatible with your project. " I tried all available versions

Comment: `-Version 3.0.1` also can't？

Comment: Have you tried creating a default demo and verifying these two lines of code?

Comment: I tried update command with version 3.0.1 but it's downloading version 4.0.20505. I'm using the default demo and copying files one by one.

Comment: You can just copy these two lines of code to see if the package is useful.

Comment: It still shows a warning but the lines are not showing an error

Comment: It seems that there are no other alternative packages. The warning does not seem to affect the use. Have you tested it?